# Mail gem not sending emails after upgrading to Rails 5.0.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, mail-gem

I upgraded my Rails app to 5.0.6 from 4.2.5. Now emails are not being sent by the [Mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail/) gem. I don't seem to be getting errors. I updated the Mail gem to the latest version with no luck. I am not sure what else to try.

I am running:

Rails 5.0.6

Ruby 2.3.0

Mail 2.7.0

*controllers/send_email.rb*

```
 class SendEmail < ApplicationController
    def initialize(to_address, from_address, email_pass, subject, body)

        begin
            options = {
                :address              => 'abc.prod.1234.secureserver.net',
                :port                 => '465',
                :domain               => 'mydomain.com',
                :user_name            => from_address,
                :password             => email_pass,
                :authentication       => :login,
                :ssl                  => true,
                :openssl_verify_mode  => 'none'
            }

            Mail.defaults do
                delivery_method :smtp, options
            end

            Mail.deliver do
                to to_address
                from from_address
                subject subject
                body body
            end

            puts("\nSent message. From: #{from_address} To: #{to_address} \nMessage body: \n#{body}")

            return true

        rescue Exception => e
            puts e.to_s
            return false
        end
    end
end
```

**Update:**

I tried sending an email with Action Mailer as well. It says it sent in the console but it never gets delivered. I am using similar settings for Action Mailer as I am for the Mail gem.

*config/environments/development.rb*

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => 'abc.prod.1234.secureserver.net',
    :port                 => '465',
    :domain               => 'mydomain.com',
    :user_name            => ENV['default_username'],
    :password             => ENV['default_password'],
    :authentication       => :login,
    :ssl                  => true,
    :openssl_verify_mode  => 'none'
}
```

I am running this from the console:

```
EmailMailer.sample_email(UserEmail.first)
```

Console output:

```
   Rendering email_mailer/sample_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer
   Rendered email_mailer/sample_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.1ms)
   Rendering email_mailer/sample_email.text.erb within layouts/mailer
   Rendered email_mailer/sample_email.text.erb within layouts/mailer (0.0ms)
   EmailMailer#sample_email: processed outbound mail in 9.4ms
```

**Solution:**

I have some code that sends an email when there is an unknown error that I need to look at. When I updated Rails that code got caught in a loop that sent a bunch of emails really fast. That caused my server provider to mark the email account as a spam account. I am not sure why my original code was not showing any errors but when I ran `EmailMailer.sample_email(UserEmail.first).deliver_now` it gave me an error message that helped me track it down.

Comment: Please post your entire config/environments/development.rb file

Comment: I cannot believe that you have a `SendEmail` that inherits from `ApplicationController` and that your mailer is named `EmailMailer`? Can you please post your actual code from your app? How does your mailer config look like? How does your mailer look like? How do you call your mailer in your application? Does your mailer setup look like it is described in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, wild guessing here but try this:

```
EmailMailer.sample_email(UserEmail.first).deliver_now
```

If you had Rails version below 4.2.1 it was not necessary [to call deliver](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery/deliver) on the mail object for it to be delivered. From that point on you can operate on the mail object before delivering it, which [can be now using](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery/deliver_now) 
 `.deliver_now` [or later, using](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery/deliver_later)  `.deliver_later`, which goes along with the use of ActiveJob or other queueing library.